# Filtering <Item> from Flow<List<Item>> in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, list, android-studio

I have a a data class named Item. Inside my viewmodel, I have Flow<List> which gets List of Items from Room db. In this program, when the user enters some text in Textfield, onSearchTextChange is invoked. Upon typing some text, I want to display in UI List field only those list items that matches the firstName or middleName or lastName with input text. How can I achieve this ?

```
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int? = null,
    val firstName: String,
    val middleName: String,
    val lastName: String,
}

class ItemListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ItemRepository
): ViewModel() {

    var itemList: Flow<List<Item>> = repository.getAllItem()
    private val _searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val searchText: StateFlow<String> = _searchText.asStateFlow()

    fun onSearchTextChange(text: String){

        _searchText.value = text                
        if (_searchText.value.isNotEmpty() && _searchText.value.isNotBlank()) {                    
            itemList = itemList.onEach { list ->
                list.filter {
                    it.queryName(text)
                }
            }
        } else{
            itemList= repository.getAllItem()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMatLatest`.

```kotlin
class ItemListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ItemRepository
): ViewModel() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val itemList: Flow<List<Item>> = searchText.flatMapConcat { text ->
        if (text.isNotBlank()) {
            repository.getAllItem().onEach { list -> list.filter { /* filter predicate */ } }
        } else {
            repository.getAllItem()
        }
    }

    private val _searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val searchText: StateFlow<String> = _searchText.asStateFlow()

    fun onSearchTextChange(text: String){
        _searchText.update { text }
    }
}
```